# Calculating program running time with outer loop running log(n) times and inner loop running k times?

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures, runtime, big-o

I found this [example problem](https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/ODSA/Books/CS2/html/AnalProgram.html) on the internet that I just cannot understand how the author came to their conclusion.

```
sum1 = 0;
for(k=1; k<=n; k*=2)    // Do log n times
   for (j=1; j<=n; j++)  // Do n times
      sum1++;`

sum2 = 0;
for (k=1; k<=n; k*=2)    // Do log n times
   for (j=1; j<=k; j++)  // Do k times
      sum2++;
```

I understand that the running time for the first loop is O(n) = nlog(n), but the author claims that for the second loop, the running time is O(n) = n.

Why is that?
The closest I can get to an answer is:

```
O(n) = k * log(n)
k = 2^i
O(n) = 2^i * log(n) ----> this is where I get stuck
```

I'm guessing some property of logarithms is used, but I can't figure out which one. Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

Comment: "O(n) = n log(n)" doesn't make sense. O(n) has a very specific meaning. You cannot say it is equal to n log(n).

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, the complexity is `sum_j 2^j`, i.e. the total number of operations in the inner loop.

As `2^j <= n`, there are `logn` terms.

This sum is equal to `2^{jmax+1} - 1`, with `2^jmax` roughly (<=) equal to `n`.

Then, effectively, a complexity O(2n) = O(n).

Answer (score 0):

`sum2++` is executed 1+2+4+8+...+K times, where K is the largest power of 2 less than or equal to n. That sum is equal to 2K-1.

Since n/2 < K <= n (because K is the largest power of 2 less than or equal to n), the number of iterations is between n-1 and 2n-1. That's Theta(n) if you want to express it in asymptotic notation.